# When would you use a class component over a functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Recently, I started learning React and I have built both functional and class components. I hear from the grapevine that functional components are preferred since they are simpler and have performance advantages, but class components are more powerful.

Can somebody explain to me the advantage of using a class component in lieu of a functional component in React?

Answer (score 1):

React has evolved quite a bit and today it is more of a preference what to use.
But should be noted that the React team is supporting more React hooks for functional components that replace or even improve upon class components. To follow up, React has performance optimizations in functional components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory allocations. As of today, there is no difference in render time between rendering class and functional components.